# How long should I record the data of walking acceleration for FFT analysis?

Tags: fourier-transform, oscillators, error-analysis, statistics, data-analysis

[image: 53s of walking acceleration with 833 points]

[image: With numpy.fft module to calculate the data]

Seems there is no apparent frequency of walking activity (it should be approximately close to 2 Hz)

Is it because the time of the data is too short?

Here is my csv file:[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PS_qeh1EufSaZd5fuvqlQcAN5l1X7pL2)

Comment: If the second figure shows a Fourier transform of the first, one would not expect to see anything when the signal is scaled on the the DC component (of the total acceleration, I guess). Measure horizontal acceleration of the foot instead?

Comment: Thanks for replying, it is truely the scale problem.

Comment: When I do a FFT I get an obvious peak around 1.23 Hz. NB subtract off the average acceleration (9.8 m/s^2) before you do the FFT.

Comment: How to properly normalize the frequency axis and absolute value axis?

Comment: As far as I remember, the help page for the matlab FFT function describes this. There are many many many pages which describe the scaling of the fft and probably the program which you are using has one as well.

Comment: Please put some labels on the axis. We can only assume that your first image uses seconds as reference. For the second image you tell us, you are not sure what the axis is showing. As the implementation and therefore the output of FFT depends on the used program (matlab, R, ...) AND on the scaling of the input, we are unable to draw conclusions.

Comment: @Semoi here are my code and data file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FWzptKUQp2dn1lCXxTCCQNOESdQkH_0x   ,   https://github.com/jamiechang917/General-Physics/blob/master/FFT_test/FFT.py

Comment: Thank you very much for the data, but I won't do that for you. This is not the idea of this website, and it's not why I am here. If you want that a random person analyse your data, I suggest you use an online FFT analyser. They exists, e.g. use google ans search for "fast fourier online". You can upload your data and you get back a FFT.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I would search online for further understanding.